# Dynamically animate an svg element

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, smil

I'm implementing a simple game, where the player is going to control a red circle in the middle of the screen. The circle is implemented as an SVG element.

I'd like to be able to move the circle between any two positions within the SVG viewBox using the SVG Animations (SMIL). The trigger of each animation is a left click anywhere on the screen.

I've [written code](https://jsfiddle.net/q2js23t3/), which, I believe, should work both in Firefox and Chrome. In Chrome it works only for the first animation, and for all subsequent animations the circle simply "teleports". In Firefox there is no animation <strike>(and no errors in the console)</strike>.

Is there a bug in my code or are there some generally known problems with SMIL being too immature?

Can I get SMIL to work in this use case or should I use canvas instead?

This is the code I've got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <svg id="canvas" width="800" height="800" onclick="Move()">
      <circle id="player1" cx="300" cy="300" r="40" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" fill="red">
      </circle>
    </svg>
    <script>

      function createAnimation(attribute, playerID, duration, from, to) {
        var animation = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animate")
        animation.setAttribute("attributeType", "XML")
        animation.setAttribute("attributeName", attribute)
        animation.setAttribute("dur", duration)
        animation.setAttribute("to", to)
        animation.setAttribute("from", from)
        animation.setAttribute("fill", "freeze")
        animationID = playerID + "animation" + attribute
        animation.setAttribute("id", animationID)
        player = document.getElementById(playerID)
        previous_animation = document.getElementById(animationID)
        if (previous_animation != null) {
          player.removeChild(previous_animation)
        }
        player.appendChild(animation)
      }

      function Move() {
        console.log(event.clientX);
        console.log(event.clientY);
        createAnimation("cx", "player1", "2s", document.getElementById("player1").getAttribute("cx"), event.clientX);
        createAnimation("cy", "player1", "2s", document.getElementById("player1").getAttribute("cy"), event.clientY);
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues...

- There's no event (or rather evt) object in Firefox unless you pass one in from the caller. This error does show up in the Firefox browser console.
- Firefox still implements SVG 1.1 animation which does not update the attribute values, you need to call animVal to get the values
- Once you've animated once, the timeline is now at 2s so the next time you animate an animation from 0-2s in a document at 2s it jumps right there. I reset the timeline to 0 each time there's a move in the answer below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <svg id="canvas" width="800" height="800" onclick="Move(evt)">
      <circle id="player1" cx="300" cy="300" r="40" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" fill="red">
      </circle>
    </svg>
    <script>
    
      function createAnimation(attribute, playerID, duration, from, to) {
        var animation = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animate")
        animation.setAttribute("attributeType", "XML")
        animation.setAttribute("attributeName", attribute)
        animation.setAttribute("dur", duration)
        animation.setAttribute("to", to)
        animation.setAttribute("from", from)
        animation.setAttribute("fill", "freeze")
        animationID = playerID + "animation" + attribute
        animation.setAttribute("id", animationID)
        player = document.getElementById(playerID)
        previous_animation = document.getElementById(animationID)
        if (previous_animation != null) {
          player.removeChild(previous_animation)
        }
        player.appendChild(animation)
      }

      function Move(evt) {
        console.log(evt.clientX);
        console.log(evt.clientY);
        createAnimation("cx", "player1", "2s", document.getElementById("player1").cx.animVal.value, evt.clientX);
        createAnimation("cy", "player1", "2s", document.getElementById("player1").cy.animVal.value, evt.clientY);
        document.getElementById("canvas").setCurrentTime(0);
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cheers! This works perfectly! How would you go about implementing multiple players shooting at each? Will resetting the clock every time a player makes a move or shoots a projectile affect the movement of the other player/ other projectiles? Replacing `document.getElementById("canvas").setCurrentTime(0);` in your code with `document.getElementById("player1").setCurrentTime(0);` doesn't seem to work anymore. Is it possible to reset the timer just for a single svg element?

Comment: I've tried to solve the problem using the group tag `<g> </g>`, here's my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/q2js23t3/3/, but it didn't work.

Comment: there's only a single timeline for the whole document. You could begin new animations at the current document time instead. If you're still stuck ask a new question.

Comment: Cheers, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/q2js23t3/4/ I'm happy with how it looks like, so "it's good enough", but there are weird "screen-tearing-like" visual artifacts in chrome. It looks better in firefox, except the first animation has a weird visual artifact (but it's smooth thereafter).

Comment: I've fixed jerking in chrome but not in firefox, simply by updating the current `cx` or `cy` attribute of player1 using the `from` value from `createAnimation` function: https://jsfiddle.net/q2js23t3/6/